# Raspbian stretch locking up?

Tags: pi-3, ssh, nextcloud

I have been running into an issue for the better part of a year where after a couple of weeks, my RPi3B+ will lock up.
Using it for Nextcloud, Apache2, php7.2, etc...

Locking up means apache starts throwing 403 errors, even when permissions have been set, I can not ssh into the board and using serial yields no output. Hooked up a monitor and keyboard, waiting for it to fail again. It wouldn't let me log in after it "locked up".
Simply unplug/replug power, boots up normally, and works for another couple of days.

Have tried the usual, SD Card swap, Power supply change(it has proper power being supplied), and used another RPi I had laying around(same board), the same issue on fresh installs within a month.

Log files yield nothing either, no error is thrown except for the 403 and connection refused. Nothing to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I've had similar issues, which I think were related to shutting down properly and filesystem corruption.

Comment: It may be worth monitoring temperature.